# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function when trying to send a value via JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP socket chat</title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 100%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>

<form action="">
    <input type ="text" id="m" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$('#messages').load('send.php', { chat_message: $('#m').value() });" />
</form>
```

I am seeing an

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function"

whenever I submit data, and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to send the data in the text field via POST to send.php.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Whenever JavaScript tells you that something "is not a function", it usually means that you're calling something that doesn't exist. jQuery has a `$(...).val()` method but no `$(...).value()` method like the one in your code.

Comment: Thanks, RJ- I was looking at the .val() doc page and saw .val() (value), thinking it meant that .value was an alternative way to call the function. Brain cramp, I guess!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no function named `value` in jquery.

```
{ chat_message: $('#m').value() }
```

It should be -

```
$('#m').val()
```

Comment: Well, don't I feel _special_. I'll accept your answer when it will let me. That's what I get for trying to learn pre-coffee...

Answer (score 2):

`$('#messages').load('send.php', { chat_message: $('#m').val() });`

Answer (score -1):

use the following command :

> element.setValue(your_input);

Answer (score -2):

Use this script on you page.

```
<script>
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain your thought to your fellow programmers. Cheers.

Comment: This dude actually helped me