# How to load a textbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my Jquery and ajax code to  load text box data sending from server
class. Am getting response so that alert inside success function executed data sent from the server browser console why its not loading to textbox
     [The error am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YstV3.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#userCheck').change(function (event) {
                    if(!$(this).is(":checked"))
                        return;
                    var userNumber = $('#userNumber').val();           
                    if(userNumber != ""){
                        $.ajax({
                            type : 'GET',
                            url : 'populateTextBox',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            data : {
                                userNumber : $('#userNumber').val()
                                },
                            success : function(data, success) {
                                alert("babu code")
                                console.log(data)
                                /* var json = data; */
                                $('#Name').value(data.name);                        
                            },
                            error : function(data, success) {
                                console.log(data)
                                document.getElementById("er").innerHTML = "Problem to upload a name";
                                er.style.color='red';
                                $('#er').show();                        
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        //FIXME: Handle this properly
                        alert("Enter User Number")
                    }
                });
            });

<s:form action="populateTextBox">
        <s:textfield name="userNumber" id="userNumber"></s:textfield>       
        <s:checkbox id="userCheck" name="userCheck"></s:checkbox>
        <s:textfield name="userName" id="Name"></s:textfield>
        <td><p id="er"></td>
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: `$('#Name').value(data.name);`

It is wrong, correct it to `$('#Name').val(data.name); ` at line 18 (if you paste this code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function when trying to send a value via JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074935/uncaught-typeerror-value-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-send-a-value-v)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#Name').val(data);
```

If `console.log(data)` is returning `pradeep` in your console, then that is all you need.

And, as Grégoire Fruleux also pointed out in the comments, use `.val()` instead of `.value()`

Comment: Use of inputEncoding is deprecated. opt_content.js:1:804232
unreachable code after return statement