# Set lat and long auto using map geolocation or any current location method

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have this working code.
my problem is how to change the long lat location based current location. 
right now it manual. how to get from table input put in the variable or geolocation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418); //Google map Coordinates
    var map;
    map_initialize(); // load map
    function map_initialize(){

        //Google map option
        var googleMapOptions = 
        { 
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            panControl: true, //enable pan Control
            zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
            zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
            scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);     
    }
});
```

the only code i need to change is the long lat.

```
 var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418); //Google map Coordinates
```

i try using variable  that i get from div but cannot insert into the long lat. The map not showing.

```
var long = $("#a").value();
var lat = $("#a").value();
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the posted code and fix the obvious problems:

- lat and long are both coming from `#a`
- you are creating `var long`, `var lat` but using `a` and `b`

I get the javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function`

Which leads to this duplicate question: [Uncaught TypeError: $(…).value is not a function when trying to send a value via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074935/uncaught-typeerror-value-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-send-a-value-v)

(There is no function named value in jquery. Should be `$('#m').val()`)

Fixing that per the above question, it works.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vhrdcnpq/6/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#google_map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="lat" value="47.6145" />
<input id="lng" value="-122.3418" />
<div id="google_map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var lng = $("#lng").val();
    var lat = $("#lat").val();
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    //Google map Coordinates
    var map;
    map_initialize(); // load map
    function map_initialize() {

      //Google map option
      var googleMapOptions = {
        center: mapCenter, // map center
        zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
        panControl: true, //enable pan Control
        zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
        scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
    }
  });
</script>
```